# Amazon Product Advertising API - Get all OfferListingID's for ASIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

As you know, it is possible that to find multiple offers for one ASIN on Amazon (different sellers), which byside compete to finally get the buy box.

Every offer for these ASIN has its unique OfferListingID, which makes it possible to address. But how can I get all the OfferListingID's for one ASIN?

Example Request:

```
http://webservices.amazon.de/onca/xml?
    AWSAccessKeyId=[AccessKey]&
    AssociateTag=[AssociateTag]&
    IdType=ASIN&
    ItemId=B00A6N2TKK&
    Operation=ItemLookup&
    ResponseGroup=Offers&
    Service=AWSECommerceService&
    Timestamp=2016-07-24T20%3A27%3A50Z&
    Signature=[Signature]
```

The Response contains only one offer with its OfferListingID:
The current buy box winner.

What I want to have is the OfferListingID for another seller, which supports Amazon Prime but is a bit more expensive. With the OfferListingID I will be able to address these specific seller for example a remote cart on my website.

If I work with parameter conditions=All 
I get the right number of TotalNew (6) but TotalOffers is still 1 and should be 6 too:

```
<Item>
  <ASIN>B00A6N2TKK</ASIN>
  <ParentASIN>B00A6N2P4K</ParentASIN>
  <OfferSummary>
    <LowestNewPrice>
      <Amount>###</Amount>
      <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
      <FormattedPrice>EUR #,##</FormattedPrice>
    </LowestNewPrice>
    <TotalNew>**6**</TotalNew>
    <TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
    <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
    <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
  </OfferSummary>
<Offers>
  <TotalOffers>**1**</TotalOffers>
  <TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages>
  <MoreOffersUrl>
```

Where is the problem in my logic? Is there another way to get a OfferListingID for an specific offer for an ASIN?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score -1):

In here as my reaserch and understanding, it refer not for offers, but about sellers

```
    <TotalNew>**6**</TotalNew>
    <TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
    <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
    <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
```

Here This item has 6 new item sellers, 0 used item sellers and so on.. It was true always with my studies on aws.